# IE8 Specific Issue - "The value of the property is null or undefined, not a Function object"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I've had a little piece of code which I use to share a sitecode between functions, I've had no problem with this until recently i've found that IE8 is throwing an error.

Definition:

```
(function siteCode(code) {
    var siteCode = code;
    getSiteCode = function () { return siteCode; }
    setSiteCode = function (code) { siteCode = code; }
})();

(function employeeCode(code) {
    var employeeCode = code;
    getEmpCode = function () { return employeeCode; }
    setEmpCode = function (code) { employeeCode = code; }
})();
```

Usage inside another function:

```
if (!SiteCode) {
    SiteCode = getSiteCode();  // This line errors in IE8
}
```

"Sitecode" is an argument, If it isn't passed to the function I wish to load the stored copy, This works in everything but IE8.

Would someone be able to talk me through my issue please?

Comment: Have you tried removing the names from the function expressions? Also, in which line exactly does the error originate?

Comment: @FelixKling I've added a comment on the line it fails, and does removing the names not defeat the purpose of the function? I want to have a "global" scoped sitecode which can only be accessed via the function getSiteCode() or setSiteCode()

Comment: I was talking about the name of the function `function siteCode(code) { ... }` since you are not using it anyway. But I guess that's not the issue. Make sure the code is actually executed and try to  create explicit globals (`window.getSiteCode = ...`) rather than implicit ones.

Comment: @FelixKling The reason I used this code was that I do not wish sitecode to be global though, so I used a closure. The only way I can access the "Sitecode" variable was by calling either getSiteCode() or setSiteCode("xxxx"). The code is executed and works as expected on everything but IE8 :/

Comment: I understand the purposes of the code. But again, you are not using the function names of the IIFEs. Instead of `(function foo() { ... }())` you can just write `(function() { ... }())`. And obviously `getSiteCode` and `setSiteCode` are global, right?